# Activating php on javascript with keypress

Tags: javascript, php, html

i want to activate my php code with the use of an assigned key which is "q"
is it possible to send php code by a keypress?

here is my code:

```
<?php 
    $name = "soma";
?>

<script>
    document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
        var keyCode = evt ? (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) : event.keyCode;
        if (keyCode == 81) {

            //i want to put my php code here
            // <?php $sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO tb_x (`name`)VALUES('$name')");

        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: You need [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) .

Comment: On what machine does the JavaScript run, and on what machine does php run?  Answer those two questions, and the answer is quite obvious.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use jquery library
then

```
if(keyCode == 81)
    {
    $.post("phpscript.php" , function(data){
        //you can put nothing here.
    }
}
```

and in phpscript.php

```
$name = "soma"
$sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO tb_x (`name`)VALUES('$name')")
```